# How to I inject only certain parts of PHP page using PHP

Tags: php, include

I know I can include other files using PHP

```
<?php include("file.php"); ?>
```

Now my question is how do I inject only certain parts of "file.php"?

Lets say I have some header code and some footer code within file.php. How do I organize file.php with the correct separated section, and how do only include certain sections of the file.php (`file.php?footer` or something like that?)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The easiest (and usual) way is to simply make separate header.php and footer.php files, and access them where you need them. There's no direct support for only loading parts of a file.

**Edit** (to respond to your comment on the other answer about using separate functions): Let's say your file.php looks like this:

```
<?php

function header() { ?>
   header content goes here
<?php }

function footer() { ?>
    footer content goes here
<?php }

?>
```

Then in the page you're calling it into, you can use `<?php header() ?>` and `<?php footer() ?>` to produce the content where you want it.

Comment: Just a note... you can't use header(), have to use something like header2()

Comment: I have a list of links I update every now and then. I wanted to make one file (not 20). Is that possible? The idea is to update wherever the links appear on the website dynamically.

Answer (score 4):

Ideally those parts would be further broken down into their own files not only for organization's sake but also so you're not including a bunch of code that will not be used.

But if you want to have those pieces all in one page you can put each piece into a function and then call the appropriate function when needed.

**EDIT:**

Basic example:

```
<?php

function printHeader()
{
?>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Test Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
<?
}

function printFooter()
{
?>
        </body>
    </html>
<?  
}

?>
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example of breaking it into functions and then calling those functions?

Comment: I've added an example with a basic header and footer function. Naturally you can make these more complex if needed.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Sir! Finnaly Got my Ans, It helps me what i was looking for
file name  test.php

```
`<?php
function printHeader() { ?>
my header test <? }
function printFooter()
{ ?> f
footer text <? }
?>`

file name  answer.php`  
<?php include('test.php');  
printFooter()   ?> `
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be a comment?