# php include only part of an external page not all of it

Tags: php, include, require

using php's include is possible to include part of another page without including all that entire content of that page?

From pageX.php i want Div #A not div #B the whole pageX.php

```
<div id="A">
<p>Don't show me</p>
</div>
<div id="B">
<p>Display Me</p>
</div>
```

i'm aware of JQuery's ajax Load but im wondering if there's a method like that in php.

Comment: wouldn't it be easiest to break the two divs out into seperate files and just include what you need?

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111974/how-to-i-inject-only-certain-parts-of-php-page-using-php

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any function that can include a specific part of a php file but typically this can be achieved in two ways.

1. Split your UI component markups into separate files so that can be included separately and easily re-used in many places. (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434319/php-to-include-specific-part-of-file))
2. Have all the UI components markups as different functions in a common file which can be called easily.

   ```
   function printDivA() {
      echo <<< DIV_A
         <div id="A">
         <p>Don't show me</p>
         </div>
      DIV_A;
    }
   ```

Comment: So you are saying I should do what I'm trying to avoid? Separate files?